# Atualizar dados da tela depois de uma chamada assincrona Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Estou com o  seguinte problema! Eu tenho um formulário com  um campo id. esse cara é passado para meu método GET que é assíncrono. Os dados voltam perfeitamente do servidor (linha `$scope.produto = resposta.data`), Mas os dados não são atualizados na tela. Segue o método:

```
$scope.buscar = function(produto) {
    console.log(produto)
    ProdutosServices.buscar(produto).then(function(resposta) {
        $scope.produto = resposta.data;
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido galera. Meu objeto resposta voltava um array. Foi só modificar a linha:

$scope.produto = resposta.data

para

$scope.produto = resposta.data[0]